# replace the last third line of a file using awk and sed

Tags: sed, awk

I need to find the last third line of a file and if its "}," I should replace it with "}"

I was thinking of **awk** and **sed** 
This finds the last third line of file

```
 PATTERN=$(awk '{v[c++]=$0}END{print v[c-3]}' $file)
```

I wanted to use

```
 sed -i 's/$PATTERN/}/' $file
```

But this is wrong 
Don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` should do it (last third line `more` is cleaned)

```
cat file
one
two },
three
four
more }, test }, hi
five },
yes
```

```
awk '{v[++c]=$0}END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {if (v[c-3]~"},") gsub(/},/,"}",v[c-3]);print v[i]}}' t
one
two },
three
four
more }, test }, hi
five },
yes
```

Comment: @JotnBut files remaines unchanged

Comment: To change original files do: `awk (some commands) file > tmp && mv tmp file`  This will write back changes to `file`

Comment: Some thing is wrong , you may see in your example also, the first line of the file is missing !

Comment: Good catch. I just copied the original and it have `c++` that increment variable after its used, so array would then start on `0`, change to `++c`  PS, only solution that uses one single command, `awk` :)

Answer (score 4):

> I need to find the last third line of a file and if its "}," I should
>   replace it with "}"

Using `tac` and `sed`:

```
tac filename | sed '3s/^};$/}/' | tac
```

---

On MacOS, you could say:

```
sed '1!G;h;$!d' filename | sed '3s/^};$/}/' | sed '1!G;h;$!d'
```

Comment: I am running on mac and bash complains of not finding tac command